# Fetch additional data when ngIf condition is satisfied

Tags: angular

I have two simple components. One for listing users and second for detail view.

When i select a particular user, this user binds to a variable selectedUser, ngIf in detail component gets satisfied and i wanna make additional request to fetch more data related to this user.

What is the appropriate way to implement this? When i make custom ngIf function, it begins to make a ton of requests to my api, but i need it only once. Thanks!

Here is my code:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'users',
    template: `
        <div *ngFor="#user of users"
            (click)="onSelect(user)">
                {{ user.name }}
        </div>
        <user-detail [user]="selectedUser"></user-detail>
    `
export class UserComponent {
    onSelect(user: IUser) {
        this.selectedUser = user;
    }
}

@Component({
    selector: 'user-detail',
    template: `
        <div *ngIf="user">
            {{ user.name }} {{ user.id }}
            <div *ngFor="task of tasks"> <-- this is what i actually try to fetch
            </div>
        </div>
`

export class UserDetailComponent {
    @Input() user: IUser[];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest you to that `ngIf` directive over `user-detail` component usage. Then you could have `ngDoCheck` & `ng` hook inside `user-detail` component to fire desire code when `user` value of `Input` gets changed.

```
<user-detail *ngIf="selectedUser" [user]="selectedUser"></user-detail>
```

**Component**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'user-detail',
    template: `
        <div>
            {{ user.name }} {{ user.id }}
            <div *ngFor="task of tasks"> <-- this is what i actually try to fetch
            </div>
        </div>
`

export class UserDetailComponent implements DoCheck {
    @Input() user: IUser[];

    ngDoCheck(){
       //stuff which will fireup when everytime component user gets changed.
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, it works! When condition is satisfied, component is inited. But when i change the selected user, it won't init again. Should i use here ngOnChanges maybe? And can i cache the result somehow?

Comment: @v01d so then `ngDoCheck` would be approapriate instead of `ngOnInit`

Answer (score -3):

You can use an ng-if with a scope function.  As long as you return true or false, you can do the validation there and also pull extra data.

Something along the lines (in javascript):

```
var busy = false;
scope.Validate = function() {
       //Do validation
       if(/*condition*/) {
         if(!busy) {
             busy = true;
             /*Do your fetch for data and set busy = false when done*/
         }
         return true;
       }
       else return false; 
}
```

then in the element call `ng-if="Validate()"`

Comment: You can do angular with javascript too

Comment: Thanks for letting me know.. :D

Comment: Yeah the documentation still doesn't show much for angular 2 in javascript but it is there.